# Adding a custom title for each definition

Tags: tcolorbox, definition

I'm currently writing a thesis and would like to format my definitions nicely. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326625/how-organize-definitions-in-a-thesis-document) helped me creating a nice layout for my definitions. The following code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=defs,number within=section]{definition}[2][]{title={Definition~\thetcbcounter},colback={white!30!yellow},colbacktitle={gray},coltitle=black,#1}

\newcommand{\listofdefinitions}{%
 \tcblistof[\section*]{defs}{List of Definitions}
}
\begin{document}
\listofdefinitions

\chapter{Foo}

\section{Foobar}

\begin{definition}[label=latex]{On \LaTeXe}
 \LaTeXe is very nice!
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[label=MWE]{On MWE}
Providing a MWE helps
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

produces this output:
[image]

What I would like to have, however, is a way to create my own custom definition titles for each definition. I.e. instead of "Definition 1.1.1" and "Definition 1.1.2", I would like to have ""Definition 1.1.1 - My first definition dealing with topic A" and ""Definition 1.1.2 - My second definition dealing with topic B".

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
list inside=defs,
number within=section]{definition}[2][]{
    list entry={{\bfseries\thetcbcounter~#2}},
    title={Definition~\thetcbcounter\ -- #2},% <-------------
    colback={white!30!yellow},
    colbacktitle={gray},
    coltitle=black,
    #1
}

\newcommand{\listofdefinitions}{%
    \tcblistof[\section*]{defs}{List of Definitions}
}
\begin{document}
    \listofdefinitions

    \chapter{Foo}

    \section{Foobar}

    \begin{definition}[label=latex]{\LaTeXe}
        \LaTeXe is very nice!
    \end{definition}

    \begin{definition}[label=MWE]{MWE}
        Providing a MWE helps
    \end{definition}


\end{document}
```

Just add the second argument to the title. (I copied Christian's second code in the linked question as it fixes the "list of definitions".) I marked out the relevant change in the code.

[image]